# Why does my sculpture looked so vague

Tags: sculpting

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you see in the images above, the sculpture that I made with brushes looks so vague that the final rendering looks the same, how can I solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: If you mean 'lacks high resolution detail' ? (Please be a bit more specific, if you can) then that's limited by the geometry.. you could supplement the basic form with a  painted height-map, for use with Bump or Displacement at render-time..

Comment: Thanks，@RobinBetts, what I mean is what you said, you can easily tell a lot of blocks there, and actually I've added a height map already before I upload the screenshot, I wonder if I can show the screenshot of the shader editor in the comment.

Comment: @RobinBetts and the problem is it happened before I rendered it, please see the first image.

Comment: Hello, Raymond. Thanks for the info. I think this question would be much clearer if instead of saying 'vague' (which is a bit vague :) ) you gave us a clear description of what you want, compared with what you've got, and how you got there. (including details like the shader editor screen-grab, which you can edit into your _post_, rather than a comment.  You can also share a representative sample .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/, keeping it as small and simple as you can, not forgetting to pack images into the file. If that helps.

Comment: Hi Robin, I can't upload the blender file more than 30M, you have any other idea to upload the file that more than 30M？